Is X a mental disease?
So I'm wondering what this community should do with questions in the format of 'is X a mental disease?'. Here's the latest one question...
Psychology behind siblings falling in love
...which is receiving close-votes as we speak. I find this particular question a lot less troublesome than...
Within psychiatry, how is homosexuality discussed or classified?
...where OP basically asks whether gay people are mentally ill. 
Why is the first one being regarded as OK, and has actually received lots of support from this community while it raised a lot of offense, and is the second related question receiving close votes?

There are two close votes so far. One 'too broad', and one 'unclear what you are asking'. Both are accurate and do not necessarily mean the topic is not welcome here. As any question, there simply needs to be more specificity and ideally some related work on which it is based to make it more acceptable. What exactly is he interested in? He could easily narrow the question down by asking 'how common' it is, rather than the broadly formulated 'psychology behind (anything goes)'.

@StevenJeuris I understand the wording of the 2nd question is not too great, but it's obvious the question can be re-stated as "are people loving close family members mentally ill?".

Well, it could be, or not. Closing the question down and asking the OP for clarification is the way to go.

I don't mind the content of the top question. As to why the bottom one received support, I think that a main reason may be that homosexuality was classified as a mental disease for a reasonably long period of time. Also, the top question hasn't stirred the provocative and abusive responses that the bottom one did (yet), which in my mind was the main reason the bottom one got closed (not necessarily content).
